# Once I load an excel sheet containing a simple table of data into Python using pd.read_excel, I simply cannot manipulate the data

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I load the xlsx file using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("petr3.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
```

and everything is fine, I can run a `print(df)` and see that the data is there, but I'm unable to retrieve any data from the table. For instance, if I want to store the column that goes by the name of 'data', I try this:

```
df["data"]
```

and I get an error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 df["data"]
>
> KeyError: 'data'

All the tutorials that I've read, give the same tips and I've tried replicating them but the errors are similar.

(My pandas version is 0.23.0.)

Comment: Can you show what the excel file looks like?

Comment: data test
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
5 10
6 12
7 14
8 16
9 18
10 20
11 22

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better. The excel is just two columns, one is called 'data' the other is 'test' and there are numbers under each header. The same amount of numbers for each column

Comment: @VictorPani what is `df.columns` make sure it is 'data' and not something like 'data '

Comment: The output of print(df.columns) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-836580d537b0> in <module>()
----> 1 print(df.columns)

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: From the traceback, it looks like your df is an OrderedDict and **not a DataFrame**, is there any code between you reading and trying to access the data. If any please avail it.

Comment: @VictorPani did your q get answered?

Comment: Yes! Everything worked as expected. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("petr3.xlsx", headers=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = pd.read_excel("petr3.xlsx", headers=None, names=['data', 'test'])
```